# jQuery Form Validate not posting when using file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I've been using jQuery Validate plugin without problems for a while now, but not that I'm trying to use it with a file upload it does not work.

Im getting no post, and the page just reloads too quickly for me to see the "illegal" error that comes up.

The jQuery is as follows:

```
_validateModalForm = function(formID, modalShow){
    var mesContainer = "#modal-message";
    $("#" + formID).validate({
        invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
            EMPGlobal.showAlert(mesContainer, '', 'danger', 'There was an error, please check the form, correct, and try again.' , '', '', '', 'warning');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form){ 
            var formData = form;
            formData = new FormData(formData);
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/pages/leads.php?',
                //data: $(form).serialize(),
                data: formData,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function(item, value){
                        if( (item == 'Success') || (item == 'Warning') ){
                            if(item == 'Success'){
                                var alertType = 'success';
                            } else {
                                var alertType = 'danger';
                            }
                            modalShow.modal('toggle');
                            EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'success', value, '', '', '', alertType);
                            $('#lead-report-range').change(); //Reset the boxes
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    message = 'A ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' error occurred. <br /> <i>Message Details: ' + returnMes + '</i>';
                    EMPGlobal.showAlert(mesContainer, '', 'danger', message, '', '', '', 'warning', jqXHR.status);
                },
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#" + formID + " input[required='required']").each(function(){
        $(this).rules( "add", {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        });
    });
};
```

It validates correctly, but just wont post over Ajax.

Any help on this one would be appreciated. I'm sure its something simple that I am missing.

**Update**

The error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
n.param.e @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
Wc @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
n.param @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
$.validate.submitHandler @ leads.js:157
d @ VM16566:4(anonymous function) @ VM16566:4
n.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
```

Comment: so what does happen? Errors? Does request get intiated in network tab?

Comment: The page refreshes with the form variables in the url bar as a get request. and just before the refresh an "illegal" error comes up in the console, but as the page refreshes I can't see what the message actually is.

Comment: put `debug:true` in validation options so form shouldn't submit ... the page load is due to errors thrown and script blocking so form is default submitting via browser.

Comment: Thanks. See update above.

Comment: ok...there are different ajax options you need for file uploads. Google around to find what they are. One is `processData:false` when you send form data. I never do ajax uploads directly...prefer using more advanced plugins for tha. So I forget the exact settings. For many years before `formData` api was exposed you couldn't even do it. Also inspect the logging of the formData object and make sure it's ok

Answer (score 0):

With the help of charlietfl managed to get this working.

```
_validateModalForm = function(formID, modalShow){
    var mesContainer = "#modal-message";
    $("#" + formID).validate({
        invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
            EMPGlobal.showAlert(mesContainer, '', 'danger', 'There was an error, please check the form, correct, and try again.' , '', '', '', 'warning');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form){ 
            var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/pages/leads.php?',
                //data: $(form).serialize(),
                data: formData,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function(item, value){
                        if( (item == 'Success') || (item == 'Warning') ){
                            if(item == 'Success'){
                                var alertType = 'success';
                            } else {
                                var alertType = 'danger';
                            }
                            modalShow.modal('toggle');
                            EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'success', value, '', '', '', alertType);
                            $('#lead-report-range').change(); //Reset the boxes
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    message = 'A ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' error occured. <br /> <i>Message Details: ' + returnMes + '</i>';
                    EMPGlobal.showAlert(mesContainer, '', 'danger', message, '', '', '', 'warning', jqXHR.status);
                },
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```